# How to add a variable to Python plt.title?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I am trying to plot lots of diagrams, and for each diagram, I want to use a variable to label them. How can I add a variable to `plt.title?` For example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure(1)
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.xlabel('x')

for t in xrange(50, 61):
    plt.title('f model: T=t')

    for i in xrange(4, 10):
        plt.plot(1.0 / i, i ** 2, 'ro')

    plt.legend
    plt.show()
```

In the argument of `plt.title()`, I want `t` to be variable changing with the loop.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can change a value in a string by using `%`. Documentation can be found [here.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting)

For example:

```
num = 2
print "1 + 1 = %i" % num # i represents an integer
```

This will output:

> 1 + 1 = 2

You can also do this with floats and you can choose how many decimal place it will print:

```
num = 2.000
print "1.000 + 1.000 = %1.3f" % num # f represents a float
```

gives:

> 1.000 + 1.000 = 2.000

Using this in your example to update `t` in the figure title:

```
plt.figure(1)
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.xlabel('x')

for t in xrange(50,61):
    plt.title('f model: T=%i' %t)

    for i in xrange(4,10):
        plt.plot(1.0/i,i**2,'ro')

    plt.legend
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 19):

You can use print formatting.

1. `plt.title('f model: T= {}'.format(t))` or
2. `plt.title('f model: T= %d' % (t))`     # c style print

Answer (score 17):

You can also just concatenate the title string:

```
x=1
y=2
plt.title('x= '+str(x)+', y = '+str(y))
```

will make the title look like

> x= 1, y = 2

Comment: if it ain't broken don't fix it!