# how to set title for plotly express figures?

Tags: python, visualization, plotly-express

I have written a function to create a bar plot of a list of data frames.
I chose this option because of the nature of the data I have and I thought it would be fun.

The code below functions fine, however these plots have no titles.

Is there a way to add this with a `fig.update_*` ??

I have tried adding the `.text` method to the end of the list as a variable however I end up with a string of every observation instead of the dataframes.

```py
def generate_bar_plot(list_of_dfs):
    for idx, df in enumerate(list_of_dfs): 
        fig = px.bar(df, x='Month', y='Transportation_Cnt', color='Transportation')
        fig.update_xaxes(tickmode='linear')
        fig.show ()


generate_bar_plot(all_avg_cnt_by_month_list)
```

I have tried adding the .text method to the end of the list as a variable however I end up with a string of every observation instead of the dataframes.

```py
def generate_bar_plot(list_of_dfs):
    for idx, df in enumerate(list_of_dfs):
        title = df.text
        fig = px.bar(df, x='Month', y='Transportation_Cnt', color='Transportation', title={title})
        fig.update_xaxes(tickmode='linear')
        fig.show ()


generate_bar_plot(all_avg_cnt_by_month_list)
```

Comment: Might you please [edit] your question to include your code, errors and other textual content as **text** rather than as screen shots?  On Stack Overflow images shouldn't be used for textual content, see [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why. For help with formatting, see [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: To include a title in `plotly.express`, simply specify a string for the title. `fig = px.bar(df, x='Month', y='Transportation_Cnt', color='Transportation',title='title_text')`

Answer (score 0):

I found an alternate solution to this issue on another stack.

[How to add a variable to Python plt.title?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43757820/how-to-add-a-variable-to-python-plt-title)

The link is above.  It shows how to call the title as an object in matplotlib.